# How to check if a radiobutton was already checked, after it has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click listener on my radiobuttons.

I need to check whether a radiobutton was already checked prior to the click, or if it wasnt.

```
$('.GridRadio').live('click', function () {
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

However, the above alerts true every time. How can i see if it was checked already, prior to when being clicked?

Comment: You can subscribe to change instead of click, that way you know that it was not checked before, but you wont trigger the event when you click ones that are already checked - http://jsfiddle.net/AXfdy/

Comment: NB: IMHO if you need to do this, then there is something wrong with your GUI concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `data()` to store the previous value of the radio, and then check the current value against that:

```
$(".GridRadio").click(function() {
    var lastValue = $(this).data("last-value");
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (lastValue == value) {
        alert("Already checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("Not previously checked");
    }

    $(".GridRadio").data("last-value", "");
    $(this).data("last-value", value);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/zRcYG/3/)

If you set the `checked` attribute on one of the radios in HTML on page load, add this code to set the `data` for that specific one:

```
$(".GridRadio:checked").data("last-value", $(".GridRadio:checked").val())
```

Comment: What if it has never been clicked but was set to checked in the html?

Comment: Seems to be the best solution, +1

Comment: Clicking on one radio button, clicking on another radio button, then clicking back on to the first radio button displays the "Already checked" alert, which seems incorrect to me. Clearing the "last-value" data attribute on all `.GridRadio` elements prior to calling `$(this).data("last-value", value);` should solve that problem, though.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, updated. This solution is getting uglier by the minute.

Comment: I have multiple groups of radiobuttons with the class GridRadio. It's a questionnarie. I think that $(".GridRadio").data("last-value", ""); would mess things up for all other groups except the current, as there would be no last-value?

Comment: @Kenci in which case you need to assign each group it's own class, the duplicate this code for each class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `live` you probably append `$('.GridRadio')` after `$(document).ready`. if that's right - you can do this check when you append it.
then when it is being clicked - it will always be the negative value.

(and if it is in the page from the beginning - you can do this check once the page is reloaded, before someone clicks on it.)